# Flyway: unable to load custom config file in cmd line

Tags: flyway

I created a new config file called "compare.conf" & placed it in 'conf' folder.

When I run the below command, I get the following error:

PS C:\Projects\Learning\Test\flyway-3.2.1> **.\flyway -configFile=conf\compare.conf info**

Flyway 3.2.1 by Boxfuse

ERROR: Unable to load config file: C:\Projects\Learning\Test\flyway-3.2.1\conf\compare

If I run  the same command with absolute URL like below, it works fine. Is this a known issue in Flyway?

PS C:\Projects\Learning\Test\flyway-3.2.1> .\flyway -configFile=**C:\Projects\Learning\Test\flyway-3.2.1\conf\compare.conf** info

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @DarshanaPatel: Sorry for late response, I somehow missed your comment. Had to update Flyway to 4.2.0 version.

Answer (score -1):

Use System property switch `-Dflyway.configFile=xxx.properties` instead of command line switch `-configFile=xxx.properties`